# Triggering a list with CSS3 animations and Sass @for loop

Tags: css, animation, sass, css-animations, keyframe

I'm trying to create a keyframe animation in Sass with a for loop, but I'm stumbling on the writing of it.  What I would like is have each single item to appear one after the other but with a minor delay. Sort of like a stacking of cards.

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/intercoder/pen/fa357090a499966b9d3b658cb991fb56/). Here is the code:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="Labs">Labs</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
   box-zising: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-zising: inherit;
}

html, body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: black;
  font-size: 1rem;
}


ul {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: red;

  @for $i from 1 through 4 {
    &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
      animation: slideTop;
      animation-duration: 1.5s + (40ms * $i);
      animation-iteration-count: 5;
      animation-delay: 2.5s + (40ms * $i);
    }
  }

  a {
    display: block;
    padding: 50px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  }
}


@keyframes slideTop {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scaleY(50px);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see here > [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wjgfy4mm/)

you have to set a much bigger `animation-delay` so you can see that the `li`s appear one after the other

and you have to set `opacity:0` together with `animation-fill-more:forwards` so at first the `li`s are hidden and then they appear and stay with `opacity:1`

let me know if this is what you were looking for

CODE :

( snippet not working because it doesn't have SASS; i've only put it so that the code is visible here on the site )

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
   box-zising: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-zising: inherit;
}

html, body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: black;
  font-size: 1rem;
}


ul {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: red;
  opacity:0;
  @for $i from 1 through 4 {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      animation: slideTop;
      animation-duration: 1s + ($i*400ms);
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation-delay: 2.5s + ($i*400ms);
      animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    }
  }
  a {
    display: block;
    padding: 50px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  }
}


@keyframes slideTop {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scaleY(50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="Labs">Labs</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. BTW how do you embed `snippets` here to make them run.

Comment: when you post an answer or question. on the top action bar . there is a button with `<>` on it saying `JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet` . click on that. and then insert HTML CSS JS in their containers :) and voila.

Glad i could help.  cheers :d